# GNU Screen: Indicate if C-a (escape) is pressed in hardstatus

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

Been searching around for this one without much luck. What I want is something that tells me if I've pressed C-a in Screen. Vim displays "-- INSERT --" when insert mode is selected. Something like that would be handy to have in Screen's hardstatus. Anybody got some suggestions on how to do this (if it's really possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't possible in the current version of screen.

That said, I usually just hit C-a (again) to check if I'm uncertain... If nothing happens, you know it's ready for a command; if it changes window (or tells you there are no other windows) then you know you are "clear".

Answer (score 2):

[source](http://adb.cba.pl/gnu-screen-tips-page-my.html#howto-escape-status)

> For a long time I got often baffled in
>   Screen just because I didn't know if
>   escape key was pressed. It was so
>   until Ben Love came up with a patch
>   which adds a new hardstatus escape for
>   escape key ( [bug #27713](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?27713) ). Download
>   [this patch](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/download.php?file_id=19528) and apply it to recent
>   Screen sources. This patch adds a new
>   hardstatus escape %E. Simplest
>   possible usage:

```
# invert colors when escape key active
# %{+s} is activated when %E is true 

hardstatus string %?%E%{+s}%?%w

hardstatus alwayslastline
```